# Android ADB shell: Enable USB app installation

Tags: android, apk, adb, usb-debugging

I have a question about APK installation internals.

If you want to install an APK on some Android devices via ADB (`adb install APK.apk` or `pm install /data/local/tmp/APK.apk`) you have to enable USB installation in Developer Options. If the USB installation is not enabled, you'll be presented an error on installation, most likely something like

```
adb: failed to install app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Installation blocked]
```

**My questions are:**

- How is enabling/disabling of the USB installation implemented in the system? At what point does the error above occur?
- Is there a way how to enable USB app installation via ADB? I know I could write a script that calls `input tap X Y` or similar GUI commands, but that's not what I want. What I'd like to know is whether there is an entirely non-GUI way of doing this, something like `setprop install.via.usb 1` or `echo 1 > /system/etc/install_via_usb`

I'm interested in ways to do this for both **rooted** and **unrooted** devices.